# Which WCF binding is most performant for cloud?

Tags: wcf, amazon-ec2, cloud, wcf-binding

In my current project which is still in development, I have three layers. Each layer is made up of **WCF** service, consuming a service below it with **basicHttpBinding** currently.
Upon completion the project will be hosted on Amazon EC2.
There the services **may or may not be** deployed on same machine. So we can not use NetNamedPipeBinding. What will be the best binding with which the services should be configured so that they are highly performant, considering **all of them** will be on cloud.

Any guidance appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you think to deploy your service in cloud then security and performance are two main concerns as per my knw. I would like to suggest you to use ‘**WS2007FederationHttpBinding**’. Both concerns are completely full-fill through this binding type. This binding provides transport and message level security based on **WS-Trust** specification.It also suitable for cloud because this binding provides claim based identity and service control access security.

If we talking abt performance, it’s little bit slow compare to **basiHttpBinding** because of message level security provide token based bt I can’t see any major impact. I’m working with this binding from last 1 year bt never see any major performance hit. My all ‘**WS2007FederationHttpBinding**’ supported services return up to 10K complex objects within single call. It’s took hardly 3 to 4 seconds max.

**Limitation**

**WS2007FederationHttpBinding** binding is working fine if you call that service form Microsoft technology only.  If you want to make it platform independent then I can’t see any options except REST Full binding. In that case, you have to use ‘**webHttpBinding**’